# Как делать такие тени картинки, разделение страницы?

Tags: css, графика

Очень интересует данный вопрос, так как столкнулся с ним в процессе верстки. Перепробовал методы из интернета не получалось ничего похожего, только обычная тень от планшетов выходила, но это не то.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уверен это это составной объект из разных частей, сами тени это линейный градиент с темнопрозрачного на прозрачный, с наклоном.

Comment: https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=Long%20Shadows&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

Long Shadow sass миксин для тени иконки + обычная тень или псевдоэлемент для угла стр.

Answer (score 0):

Вот как пример, тут можно играть сколько угодно:

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh
}
.object {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0.99;
}
.object span {
 //background-color: white;
 border: 5px solid white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 
 z-index: 1;
}
.object::before, .object::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), transparent);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  z-index: -1;
}

.object::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="object">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: подправил как тени

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на основе Ruslan Semenov

Если что то отображается не так то [песочница](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ZqQOWq) присутствует

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: darkgreen;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 150vw;
  height: 150vh;
  background: lightgreen;
  transform: rotate(-19.5deg)translate(0, -64.5%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9;
}

.items:after {
  content: "";
  border-left: 0 solid pink;
  border-top: 59vh solid transparent;
  border-right: 100vw solid green;
  border-bottom: 0 solid green;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}


/***************/

.object {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0.99;
  z-index: 20;
}

.object span {
  //background-color: white;
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.object::before,
.object::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 70%;
  height: 150px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), transparent);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  z-index: -1;
}

.object::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="object">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```